deserialize an abstract class with enum in spring
Let's say we have a class InstantMessage, which has an abstract child IMContent content.
public class InstantMessage {
    // other fields
    private MessageType type;
    private IMContent content;
}

public enum MessageType {
    TEXT, IMAGE, VIDEO, PRODUCT, SHOPPING_ORDER, SYSTEM;
}

public abstract class IMContent {
    public abstract String toText();
}

IMContent has a lot of implementations, like IMTextContent, IMImageContent, which depends on the type of message.
When using InstantMessage in the @RequestBody and @RequestPart, Spring cannot deserialize the IMContent.
I have tried several methods but they all have some obvious flaws.
Firstly, I tried adding @JsonDeserialize(using = IMContentDeserialzer.class) to the content, but that requires me to deserialize other fields manually besides content, which is every inconvenient and easy to forget when adding another field. I can accept that I write the deserialization of IMContent manually but not the entire InstantMessage. I wish there is a simple way to deserialize "non-content" fields.
My second attempt was using @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes, but that seems to require me to move the type from InstantMessage to the IMContent. It is also inconvenient when I need to access the type from InstantMessage directly or just access the text content directly. For example if I need to search the text content, I need to flatten the content into a String in the database and when I fetch the InstantMessage out of db I need to resemble the content again.
I also have some workarounds, like using Map instead of the IMContent, or deserializing content into IMContent on the fly, or making InstantMessage abstract, but they are not elegant I think.
What's the easiest way to solve this problem in this case?
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type",
        visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IMTextContent.class, name = "TEXT"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IMImageContent.class, name = "IMAGE"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IMProductContent.class, name = "PRODUCT"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IMShoppingOrderContent.class, name = "SHOPPING_ORDER"),
})
public abstract class IMContent {

    public abstract String toText();

}

